# The convex conjugate of a quadratic form with positive semi definite matrix

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

I want to find the convex conjugate (Legendre transform) of a quadratic for $1/2x^{t}Qx$ when $Q$ is positive semi-definite. If Q is non-singular, the solution is easy - the gradient is $y-Qx=0$ so $y=Q^{-1}x$ is the value for which the supremum is attained. But what should I do when Q is singular? In case there is some y for which $y=Qx$ (i.e. $y\in Image(Q)$) the solution is the same. But if it isn't - how can I prove the sup is infinite?

Answer (score 4):

It's useful to know how to minimize a quadratic function $f(x) = \frac12 x^T Q x - b^T x$ when $Q \succeq 0$.  Note that $f$ is convex, so minimizing $f$ is equivalent to solving $\nabla f(x) = 0$, which is equivalent to $Qx = b$.

If $b \in R(Q)$, then $Qx = b$ has a solution, which is a minimizer of $f$.

If $b \not \in R(Q)$, we can show that $\inf_x f(x) = -\infty$.  Let's use the fact that $R(Q) = N(Q)^\perp$.  Decompose $b$ as $b = u + v$ where $u \in N(Q)$ and $v \in R(Q)$ (so $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal).  Note that $u \neq 0$.  Now observe that 
\begin{align*}
f(\lambda u) &= -(u + v)^T (\lambda u) \\
&= - \lambda \|u\|^2
\end{align*}
which approaches $-\infty$ as $\lambda \to \infty$.

Comment: Is R(Q) the image of the transformation Q? (i.e. ${Qx all x in Rn?)

Comment: Yes, that's right.  The part about decomposing $b$ is easy if you've internalized the "four subspaces" picture that Gilbert Strang emphasizes.

Comment: @littleO: Is there a closed form expression for the conjugate when $b \in R(Q)$.

Comment: @pikachuchameleon Yes: $\tfrac12(Q^{-1}b)^TQ(Q^{-1}b)-b^T(Q^{-1}b)=-\tfrac12b^TQ^{-1}b$